# Taking produce to Europe

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink

[Vidalia onions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidalia_onion) are in season here at home (Georgia, USA), and I'd like to take some with me on my upcoming trip to Europe. I know some countries are super-sensitive about importing fresh food (U.S., Australia, New Zealand, ...?) but I've never been asked about food when entering Europe, so I suspect this is okay, but want to make sure before I try. I'll land in Amsterdam en route to Sweden for a few days, and then on to Switzerland. Will I have trouble taking onions (in my hand baggage) to any of those countries?

Note, [this question is related](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62719/bringing-plants-on-a-plane-from-us-to-denmark), but specifically about Denmark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's the biosecurity directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:02000L0029-20090303). It mentions onion (*Allium cepa*) several times, in particular to say that onion bulbs *intended for planting* must be inspected for harmful organisms before being brought into the Union.

Conversely, one infers that onions *intended for eating* are not subject to any inspection requirement.

If you want to be completely sure, go through the "goods to declare" lane when you first arrive, and declare your onions. You'll probably be told it's fine and sent on your way.